# CakePHP Unable to insert to database (datetime format)

Tags: database, datetime, cakephp, insert

I was new to Cakephp and I actually following the tutorial of the Blog tutorial however I didn't follow their database and try my own.
Currently my database:

My Model:

```
class FypCakephp extends AppModel  {
//Table Name
 public $useTable = 'Report';
 public $primaryKey = 'report_id';}
```

My Controller:

```
  public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('POST')) {  //Submited the form:takes a single argument, which can be the request METHOD (get, put, post, delete) or some request identifier (ajax). 
        $this->FypCakephp->create();// Create a model 

        // can use the pr() or debug() functions to print it out if you want to see what it looks like.
       echo pr(($this->request->data));
       debug($_POST);


        if ($this->FypCakephp->save($this->request->data)) { //Save to Database and return true. 
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
          //  return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); //Redirect to the first page
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your Database.')); //Else will show unable to add 
    }
}
```

My View:

### http://gyazo.com/a69dd4cdfcf008b76d5c3dc5392d2009

Everytime I debug they will show me this
http://gyazo.com/7f8f43cbd88aee555aeb6690f33093e0

and they forever took 0 query.
When I change the datetime to text type. They also only able to insert the created and modified .
May i know what is the reason that cause it ?

Comment: 1. From Controller incase of debug use the following lines pr($this->FypCakephp->validationErrors); So that It will print the validation errors 2. Your model not have any validation rules, If yes then make all the columns allow NULL values in table and try

Comment: @Annamalai.Somasundaram they only return me "array()" and I not understand what that mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in view :) 
Change report to Report. 
Now when you are saving $this->request->data its trying to find Report key to be able to save , or report field in your database.
If you dont want change this , in controller you can save $this->request->data['report']

Edit
Also if the first option will not work try FypCakephp instead of report in view. 
Its must be alias of your model , in your case it is FypCakephp. 
Also its not a good idea to keep model and table with various names and try too keep name conventions for cakephp (table name report instead Report), but it maybe good for understanding all options :)

Answer (score 1):

@Beginnerk. I saw the above code. Form cakephp point of view, I think its not well structural. In the beginner stage please read the [CakePHP 2.x documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/_downloads/en/CakePHPCookbook.pdf) first. Then try to developed a basic crud application. 
I give the a post link for you.

[Creating a CakePHP CRUD Example – Source Code Download and Tutorial](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2012/04/cakephp-2x-crud-tutorial.html)

**Update - 1**

As per as your code save `datetime` into database

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('POST')) {

      //Submited the form:takes a single argument, which can be the request METHOD (get, put, post, delete) or some request identifier (ajax). 
        $this->FypCakephp->create();// Create a model 
        $data = $this->request->data;

        $updated_date = date('Y-m-d H:m:i', strtotime($data['FypCakephp']['updated_date']));
        $data['FypCakephp']['updated_date'] =  $updated_date;

        // can use the pr() or debug() functions to print it out if you want to see what it looks like.
       echo pr($data);
       debug($_POST);


        if ($this->FypCakephp->save($data)) { //Save to Database and return true. 
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
          //  return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); //Redirect to the first page
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your Database.')); //Else will show unable to add 
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually just wanted learn how to save the datetime format into database.
However the tutorial provided doesn't include the Datetime

Comment: Thank you . 
However the database still unable to insert or they show this query 
"INSERT INTO `fyp_seatmanagment`.`Report` (`modified`, `created`) VALUES ('2015-06-16 09:40:19', '2015-06-16 09:40:19')"

Comment: What is the attribute name in `report` table? if its `created/modified`, you should set the value before save model.

Comment: The attribute is 
report_id ,updated_date,sector_code,occupied,created and modified

Comment: Explain the `table describe` . of your system

Comment: In cakephp you dont need to feel created and modified fields manually , its doing it instead of you , you only need to add that fields in database with datetime format

Comment: @u2460470 I solved the problem . Thank for trying to help me the problem. Appreciate Alot . :)